# pause(not stop) a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop that read the contents from a file line by line, I need to pause the loop and if button clicked resuming  the loop from where it paused. I searched the internet but I just find a stop button functionality using break for example but I don't want to break from for loop I want to pause/resuming the loop.
thank you in advance for your help
here my loop with stop and break, I need to add pause button functionality to it.

```py
running[0] = True

def csv_exe():
    with open(file_path.get(), 'r') as file:
        data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        
        for line in data:
            lines= line
            if running[0]== False:
                    break
            else:
                
                    sendmMsg.set(lines)
                    print(lines)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: How exactly are *buttons* involved at all here, what UI framework or other environment are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "yield". The pseudo code would be like below.

```
def csv_exe():
      with open(file_path.get(), 'r') as file:
           data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
           
           for line in data:
                lines= line
                if running[0]== False:
                     yield
                else:
                     sendmMsg.set(lines)
                     print(lines)
                     time.sleep(0.5)


generator=csv_exe()
while True:
  try:
     # if specific button is pressed:
         next(generator)
  except StopIteration:
     break
```